# How to say "Ok, then I take X" after your first choice is not available

Tags: colloquial-language, english-to-japanese

Imagine you are in a restaurant and you want to order food, you choose your dish but the waiter says that it is not available today.

In English I would now probably say something like

> Ok, then I take curry

What is the natural way of saying this in Japanese? I'm asking about the "Ok, then" part.

As of now, I would probably just say

> Hmm えとー カレーをおねがいします.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For casual, which is acceptable as a client I would go with

> じゃあ、カレーにします。

If you want to be more polite then

> それなら、カレーにします。

じゃあ means : then; well; so; well then
それなら means : if that's the case

Comment: ah I thought about Jaa, but was not so sure. Thank´s

Comment: Or equivalently, 「では」．

Comment: Was going to suggest 「そしたら」 but it might not be [標準語{ひょうじゅんご}](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1328409473)